# Remove "index" from url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm currently defining routes for my pages in the following manner:

```
  get "home/index"

  get "photo/index"

  get "project/index"

  get "home/about"

  root :to => 'home#index'
```

However, I can only seem to be able to create a link to the photo/project index pages by using:

```
<a href="/photo/index">link</a>
<a href="/project/index">link</a>
```

In the URL, the "index" part also shows up. I can't simple use `/photo` in the `a` link, because rails throws a routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/photo"
```

How would I create a route match for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match "/photo", to: "controller#action"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code

Comment: the `, to:` part caused an error, so I had to use: `match "/photo" => "photo#index"`

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is to use match.  Don't forget to include `via` to preserve your restriction on the http method:

```
match "/photo", to: "controller#action", :via => 'get'
```